# Send float from activity to activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm beginning android developpement and i don't why my code is not working. The aim is simple : I have a main activity, a menu and a second activity. I want to send a float value from the main to the second activity and .. it's not working !

Here is my code from the main :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_about:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    case R.id.menu_home:

        return true;
    case R.id.menu_settings:        
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    case R.id.menu_battstat:
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StatsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("consumOn", 4);
        intent.putExtra("consumOff", 5);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

And the StatsActivity.class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stats_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    float consumOn  = intent.getFloatExtra("consumOn", 0);
    float consumOff = intent.getFloatExtra("consumOff", 0);

    EditText editTextA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editTextA.setText(String.valueOf(consumOn), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    EditText editTextB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editTextB.setText(String.valueOf(consumOff), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
}
```

When I launch my code, it stills 0 and not a 4 and 5. Any ideas ? Thx.

Answer (score 5):

Replace the `getFloatExtra` with

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
float yourFloat = bundle.getFloat("key");
```

Comment: Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
          
        float consumOn  = bundle.getFloat("consumOn");
        float consumOff = bundle.getFloat("consumOff"); And it's not working too ...

Comment: have you tried logging intent.hasExtra("consumOn") to see if it is actually getting passed?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that maybe the putExtra is being interpreted as int rather than a float so it cannot find it. Try replacing these lines

```
    intent.putExtra("consumOn", 4);
    intent.putExtra("consumOff", 5);
```

with

```
    intent.putExtra("consumOn", 4f);
    intent.putExtra("consumOff", 5f);
```

because you haven't actually defined their type anywhere and they aren't variables.

Comment: 'blank' numbers are treated as integers

Comment: Hello there, please consider marking this as the correct answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass bundle with your floats to intent and only then extract them

Answer (score 0):

I am actually surprised that your intent is launching at all..  it seems like you only initialize the intent in the first case try moving Intent declaration out of the switch

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

     case R.id.menu_about:
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_home:
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_settings:        
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_battstat:
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StatsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("consumOn", 4f);
        intent.putExtra("consumOff", 5f);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```