# Some of my code is not executing in android studios?

Tags: java, android, android-developer-api

In the program below used for an android app in android studios, When getPercent() from the second class(Main2Activity) is invoked, it always returns 999(the default value), and the,

> ttper = .....;

statement from the main class in the onClick() is never executed. Is there any specific reason for this? Can you guys point it out please!

This is the main activity,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

float i1m,i2m,mm,atp,assp;
float ttper=999;
boolean b=false;
EditText i1,i2,model,assignment,attendence;
Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Context cont = this;
    final Intent intent = new Intent(cont, Main2Activity.class);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //try {
            i1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.int1);
            i2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.int2);
            model=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mod);
            assignment=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.assign);
            attendence=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.attend);

            i1m = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(i1.getText()));
            i2m = Float.parseFloat(i2.getText().toString());
            mm = Float.parseFloat(model.getText().toString());
            assp = Float.parseFloat(assignment.getText().toString());
            atp = Float.parseFloat(attendence.getText().toString());
            ttper = ((i1m / 10) + (i2m / 10) + ((mm / 100) * 15) + (assp) + ((atp >= 75.0f) ? ((atp - 75) / 5) : 0.0f));

            //setValues();
            startActivity(intent);
            //}
            //catch (Exception e) {
              //  Log.e("app crash",e.getMessage());
            //}
        }
    });
}
/*void setValues()
{
   /* i1m = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(i1.getText()));
    i2m = Float.parseFloat(i2.getText().toString());
    mm = Float.parseFloat(model.getText().toString());
    assp = Float.parseFloat(assignment.getText().toString());
    atp = Float.parseFloat(attendence.getText().toString());*/
}/*
float getPercent()
{
        //float ttper=50.0f;
        return ttper;
}
}
```

This is the second activity,

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

float tper=1.0f;
String str;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        TextView v1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        MainActivity m1 = new MainActivity();
       //m1.setValues();
        //try {
            str = String.valueOf(m1.getPercent()) + "%";
            v1.setText(str);
        //}
    //catch (Exception e) {
      //  Log.e("app crash",e.getMessage());
    //}
}

}
```

Comment: maybe you should uncomment stuff

Comment: You should never use `new` to create an instance of an Activity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can not work. If you create `new MainActivity()`, your `ttper` will be `999`.

You should [pass data between Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492037/send-float-from-activity-to-activity) in this way:

1. Put the new calculated `ttper` into Intent: `intent.putExtra("ttper", ttper );`
2. Then in `MainActivity2` use `getIntent().getFloatExtra("ttper", 999.0f);`

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You have an instance of MainActivity which has a variable ttper. You modify that value.
Then in another class Main2Activity you create a NEW instance of MainActivity and try to get that value, but ttper has the default value because this is a NEW instance and it hasn't been modified yet.

What you can do is defining ttper as static:

```
static float ttper=999;
```

You can even define your function getPercent() as static so you don't have to create a new instance of this class to get the value. You would just call MainActivity.getPercent().

For more information, read: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Anyway, this is not the correct way of passing data from one activity to another. You should follow this guidelines: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: learnt a new thing about static from you! I knew the definition but didnt know what i accualy does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use extras on intents to pass data between activies.